# Bash -z if block triggering only when run from ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, bash, processbuilder

I have a java application that uses java.lang.ProcessBuilder to run a bash script.

```
    LOG.info("PlatformID = " + platformId);
    LOG.info("oldWorkflow date = " + oldDate.toString() + " workflow = " + oldWorkFlowId);
    LOG.info("newWorkflow date = " + newDate.toString() + " workflow = " + newWorkFlowId);
    final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(exportScriptLoc, platformId, oldWorkFlowId, newWorkFlowId);
    pb.directory(new File("/opt/nis/ddziak-dev/nis-hadoop"));
    final Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
    final int exitValue = p.exitValue();
    p.destroy();
    if (exitValue == 0) {
```

With the logs I confirmed the ProcessBuilder inputs.

> 15:33:04,987 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] DapWatcher - PlatformID = 10191
>
> 15:33:05,013 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] DapWatcher - oldWorkflow date = 2017-11-16T19:13:46.000Z workflow = 00047916
>
> 15:33:05,013 INFO [pool-4-thread-1] DapWatcher - newWorkflow date = 2017-11-16T21:03:42.000Z workflow = 00050837

The script it calls is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hive -S -e \"show partitions nis.subscribers partition(destinationPlatformId='$1', build='$2');\"|awk '{if(NR>1)print}'" >> subscribers.out

PARTITIONS=`hive -S -e "show partitions nis.subscribers     partition(destinationPlatformId='$1', build='$2');"|awk '{if(NR>1)print}'`
if [ -z "$PARTITIONS" ]
then
  exit 2
fi


echo "${PARTITIONS}"

hqlOut=`hive -S -hiveconf destPlatId=$1 -hiveconf newWorkFlowId=$3 -hiveconf oldWorkFlowId=$2 -f /opt/nis/ddziak-dev/nis-hadoop/dapLib/updateSubscriberHiveTable.hql`

newPARTITIONS=`hive -S -e "show partitions nis.subscribers partition(destinationPlatformId='$1');"|awk '{if(NR>1)print}'`
if [ -z "$newPARTITIONS"]
then
  exit 3
fi
```

With the echo of PATITIONS from this script I've confirmed it is passing in the same inputs from the java program

```
hive -S -e "show partitions nis.subscribers partition(destinationPlatformId='10191', build='00047916');"|awk '{if(NR>1)print}'
```

when I run the echoed command it returns

```
destinationplatformid=10191/build=00047916
```

when I call the script directly using

```
updateSubscriberHiveTable.sh 10191 00047916 00050837
```

It successfully completes.  But the java program keeps getting an exit 2 from the p.exitValue()

Does anyone know why the java program is getting an exit 2?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my ProcessBuilder instantiation to the following which provided me with the extra info I needed to discover it was a hive within java problem

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-x", exportScriptLoc, platformId, oldWorkFlowId, newWorkFlowId).inheritIO();

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2469)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:341)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1420)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SASL_PROPS
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.getHadoopSaslProperties(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getMetaStoreSaslProperties(MetaStoreUtils.java:1485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:214)
    ... 17 more
```